# SSRS casting a parameter to decimal multi select

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Im trying to cast a parameter in SSRS to a decimal. I have a in clause since its multi select. I can select 1 and it runs fine however if i select more than 1 it will say

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

I am casting my parameter in my where clause in my query statement.

WHERE  LOAD_NO IN (CAST(@Load as DECIMAL))

I am confused as to why it would bring back the syntax error if I select more than one from list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused as to why it would bring back the syntax error if I
>   select more than one from list.

**Short answer**

Because `WHERE LOAD_NO IN (CAST(1,2,N as DECIMAL))` is not a valid T-SQL statement.

---

**Long answer**

When you use a multi-value parameter in a query, reporting services will generate different queries if your parameter contains 1 value, or multiple values.

Let's simplify your example to the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LOAD_NO IN (@Load)
```

With only one value, the query will have the following format:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LOAD_NO IN (@Load)', N'@Load int', @Load=<YourValue>
```

It's a query with a parameter: `@Load`.

Now, with multiple values, the query will become

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LOAD_NO IN (<YourValue1>, <YourValue2>,<YourValueN>)'
```

The `@Load` parameter has been replaced by the list of values.

So now my advise will be to rethink the design of your query and treat `@Load` as a list of values.

We cannot provide you the best solution because it really depends on the data and only you have all the details but I could still throw some ideas.

On the top of my head I could think of:

- Cast `LOAD_NO` instead, but the execution plan may loose the benefits of indexes if any.
- In most cases, using a `IF EXISTS` when possible instead of `IN`.
- Use a subquery.

Do not hesitate to run a SQL Server Profiler to see the generated query if you have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, so I'm not sure if these options would help, but here's a couple suggestions:

1. Try putting the `CAST` on `LOAD_NO` instead:

   WHERE CAST(LOAD_NO AS VARCHAR) IN (@Load)
2. Create a `splitString` function like the accepted post here ([T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)) and access it in your `WHERE` clause:

   WHERE LOAD_NO IN (SELECT CAST(val AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.splitString(@Load, ','))